# In Flask app on Apache server, When I submit form, render_template() shows index.html on Apache server

Tags: python, html, apache

I would like to fix this issue described below.

When I submit form, it goes `@app.route('/', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])`
 with `POST method` and renders default `index.html` on Ubuntu apache server.

This is `app.py` file I have written.

```
@app.route('/', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def whoami():
    try:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            ....
            ....
            return render_template("formElement/mainForm.html", session = session, jsonData = jsonData, jsonDataItm = jsonDataItm, fstListNm = fstListNm, jsonDataAll = jsonDataAll, jsonGrp = jsonGrp)         
        return render_template('formElement/whoami.html')
    except Exception as e:
        return str(e)
```

As you can see on this code, when I submit form, the browser should render `formElement/whoami.html` page with some parameters.
But When I submit form, the browser goes to default Ubuntu `index.html` page on Apache Server.

This is `flask.wsgi` file I've made.

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/var/www/html/lm_kyan/flaskapp')

from flaskapp import app as application
```

My source files are located in `/var/www/html/lm_kyan/flaskapp`.

This is `000-default.conf` file in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled`.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ....
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    WSGIDaemonProcess flaskapp threads=5
    WSGIScriptAlias /lm_kyan/flaskapp /var/www/html/lm_kyan/flaskapp/flaskapp.wsgi

    <Directory flaskapp>
        WSGIProcessGroup flaskapp
        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
```

Please note that I have set homepage url as `http://107.150.57.190/lm_kyan/flaskapp/`.

I'm not sure why this issue happens.

Comment: Are you `POST`ing to `/` or to `/lm_kyan/flaskapp/`, it's not clear to me

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-do-i-remove-apache2-ubuntu-default-page

Comment: `<form action="/" method="post">` is in the form template.

Comment: Your app won't handle the request unless the request path starts with `/lm_kyan/flaskapp/`, from what you've told Apache. Perhaps you need to adjust the `WSGIScriptAlias`?

Comment: How can I handle it?

Comment: The request has to reach your application, so which urls are handled by it? :)